# Target Ansible nested children groups in hosts file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a hosts file that has nested children groups, something similar to:

```
 all:
  children:
   GROUP1:
    children:
        webservers:
            hosts:
                hostname1:
        sqlservers:
            hosts:
                hostname2:

   GROUP2:
    children:
        webservers:
            hosts:
                hostname3:
                hostname4:

   GROUP3:
    children:
        webservers:
            hosts:
                hostname5:
                hostname6:
        sqlservers:
            hosts:
                hostname7:
```

I can target the first layer groups successfully such as GROUP1 but, I wish to target a nested group for example GROUP1>webservers or GROUP3>sqlservers.

The documentation I could find only addresses the first layer groups.
Is there a way to do this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible doesn't actually support "nested groups". Group names are a
flat namespace, and can only be defined once in your inventory. When
you nest a group definition (like `webservers`) inside another group
(like `GROUP1`) it's really just shorthand for making a host a member
of both groups.

In other words, when you write this:

```
all:
  children:
    GROUP1:
      children:
        webservers:
          hosts:
            hostname1:
        sqlservers:
          hosts:
            hostname2:

    GROUP2:
      children:
        webservers:
          hosts:
            hostname3:
            hostname4:
```

It is identical to the following flat layout:

```
all:
  children:
    GROUP1:
      hosts:
        hostname1:
        hostname2:

    GROUP2:
      hosts:
        hostname3:
        hostname4:

    webservers:
      hosts:
        hostname3:
        hostname4:

    sqlservers:
      hosts:
        hostname2:
```

Note that the `webservers` group only contains `hostname` and
`hostname4`, because your second definition of `webservers` overrides
the first.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out for me, I guess the best way to go from here is to have 2 inventory files then, one for the 'webservers' group and one for 'sqlservers'.
Do you have a reference for this so I can document it?

Comment: This is explicit in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/hosts.yaml.